# WP_Query for a taxonomy with different taxonomy types

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a WP_Query to display a custom post type:

```
<?php

//* The Query
$obras_query = new WP_Query( array (
  'post_type' => 'obras_en_curso',
  'posts_per_page' => 4
) );

//* The Loop
if ( $obras_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

      <h3 class="title">Casas Unifamiliares - Obras en Curso</h3>

      <ul> <?php

    while ( $obras_query->have_posts() ): $obras_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li> <?php

    endwhile; ?>

      </ul> <?php

    //* Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
?>
```

Now I have created a taxonomy called "casa_unifamiliar".

This taxonomy is hierarchical, it has 2 types of "sub-taxonomies", one called "curso" and one called "finalizada". How can I Query a post with the sub-taxonomy "curso".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a taxonomy query.  Assuming that "curso" is the term slug, it would look like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'obras_en_curso',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'casa_unifamiliar',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'curso',
    ),
  ),
) );
```

For more information, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Thank you, that works, I was missing the "terms" part on every attempt I was making.